# How to render data to make Section List in React Native

Tags: react-native, native-base

iam new to react native with native base and i need to render data with Native Base list divider but i think iam doing it wrong. here is my code
`const routes = [
  { title: "Menu", content: ["Recent Article", "Categories"] },
  { title: "Social Media", content: ["Discord", "Twitch"] }
];`

```
          <List
        contentContainerStyle={{ marginTop: 120 }}
        dataArray={routes} renderRow={(data) =>
       <View>
        <ListItem itemDivider>
          <Text>{data.title}</Text>
        </ListItem>    
            <ListItem
              button
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.content)}
            > 
              <Text>{data.content}</Text>
            </ListItem>
      </View>
        }></List>
```

here is the result
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5rBs.png)

hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.content` is an array, you need to iterate to display each item separately.

Like,

```
<List
    contentContainerStyle={{ marginTop: 120 }}
    dataArray={routes} renderRow={(data) =>
      <View>
        <ListItem itemDivider>
          <Text>{data.title}</Text>
        </ListItem>
        {
           (data.content || []).map(value => {
              return (
                <ListItem
                  button
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(value)}
                > 
                  <Text>{value}</Text>
                </ListItem>
              )
           })
        }
      </View>
    }
/>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to return the list item, will update the answer